# "Lambdifying" scala Function in Java

Tags: java, scala, lambda, apache-spark, traits

Using Java and Apache Spark (that has been rewritten in Scala), faced with old API method (`org.apache.spark.rdd.JdbcRDD` constructor), that has AbstractFunction1 as it's argument:

```
abstract class AbstractFunction1[@scala.specialized -T1, @scala.specialized +R]() extends scala.AnyRef with scala.Function1[T1, R] {}
```

Because `AbstractFunction1` is an abstract class, I cant use Java8 lambdas, so I decided to wrap [scala.Function1](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function1) trait is the same with `java.util.functions.Function` but does't implements `andThen` and `compose` methods.
As a result, i create thes interface:

```
import scala.Function1;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface Funct<T, R> extends Function1<T, R>, Serializable {

    @Override
    default <A> Function1<A, R> compose(Function1<A, T> before) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    default <A> Function1<T, A> andThen(Function1<R, A> g) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

IDE has no problems with this interface, but while compiling, a get:

```
[ERROR] Funct is not a functional interface
[ERROR] multiple non-overriding abstract methods found in interface Funct
```

Is it possible to wrap Scala's trait, that i can use lambdas for method:

```
void doMagic(scala.Function1<T,V> arg)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you want a functional interface version of the scala function traits so you can call them with java8 lambda syntax? You don't have to do this yourself. Take a look at https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat . Its not quite as nice as directly using java8 lambda syntax, since you still have to do

```
import static scala.compat.java8.JFunction.*;
doMagic(func(x => ...));
```

instead of

```
doMagic(x => ...);
```

But in Scala 2.12 a big theme will be Java8 compatibility. The scala FunctionX classes themselves will be redone as SAM interfaces, so you will be able to do the latter when scala 2.12 comes out. At least that was the plan last time I checked.

Comment: Generally, you catched my idea. JavaAPI calls to spark are wrapped to allow using lambdas. E.g. method `javardd.map(Function<T,E> arg)` - arg `org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function` is a funct. interface. But somewhere, old api is not fully adapted and there are methods like `javardd.map(scala.Function1<T,E> arg)` (or derived abstract classes), and Function1 is not a FI here from the Java's point of view.
Thank you for lib, but it is only case where there is such problem and I dont want use full comparability kit only for one case. That is why I wrote a custom interface.

Comment: Makes sense. Maybe you can just look at the source of scala-java8-compat to see how they do it?